# Triggering Code when a specific value is inserted into a table column in an Azure SQL Table

Tags: triggers, alert, azure-sql-database

I am seeking suggestions on methods to trigger the running of code based on specific event occurring.

Basically I need to monitor all inserts into a table and compare a column value against a parameter set in another table.

For example, when a new record is added to the table and the column [Temperature] is greater than 30 (which is a value set in another table). Send an alert email to notify of this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trigger (special type of stored procedure) that is automatically executed after an insert happened. Documentation for triggers is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.120).aspx

You will not be able to send an email out of SQL Database though.

Depending on how quick you need the notification after the insert, maybe you could make an insert into yet another table from within the trigger and query this new table periodically (e.g. using a script in Azure automation) and have the email logic outside the database.